# Comparing Date In Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, momentjs, parse-javascript-sdk

I have some problem with comparing to dates in Parse Cloud Code using moments.js

I'm sending new ETA of a client and compare it with the ETA saved in server.

The time in client looks fine, but when i send it to Cloud Code i changed by 2 hours.

Here is the log of my Cloud Code:

Set ETA at first time:

```
Input: {"orderID":"S9Aztq5Hky","userETA":"20:27"}
```

ETA Update Log (The comparison made here):

```
I2016-01-10T18:15:03.913Z]User New ETA: Sunday, January 10th 2016, 6:15:03 pm GMT+0000

I2016-01-10T18:15:05.873Z]User Current ETA Value: Sunday, January 10th 2016, 8:27:46 pm GMT+0000
```

What do I miss?
Why does the time change?

Thanks.

Comment: Timezone. Where does the time come from and how are you using it exactly?

Comment: First, I'm getting Route Total time from Google Direction API 2.0 and add it to current time. than i send only hh:mm to Parse Cloud and save it. `userETA = request.params.userETA;
 var elem = userETA.split(':');
 var etaDate = new Date();
 etaDate.setHours(elem[0]);
 etaDate.setMinutes(elem[1]); tmpOrder.set("UserETA",etaDate);
   tmpOrder.set("TimeToBeReady",etaDate);
   tmpOrder.save();`

Comment: So your client code is most likely not a UTC time

Comment: @Wain OK, so what should i do to be able to compare the time from client and server?